# Kinesis Stream not getting the logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis

I am receiving cloudtrail logs in Kinesis data stream. I am invoking a stream processing lambda function as described [here](https://github.com/MarcusRosen/blog/blob/master/Streaming-Log-Delivery/KinesisEventReceiver.py). The final result that gets returned to the stream is then stored onto an S3 bucket. As of now, the processing fails with the following error file created in the S3 bucket:

```
{"attemptsMade":4,"arrivalTimestamp":1619677225356,"errorCode":"Lambda.FunctionError","errorMessage":"Check your function and make sure the output is in required format. In addition to that, make sure the processed records contain valid result status of Dropped, Ok, or ProcessingFailed","attemptEndingTimestamp":1619677302684,
```

Adding in the Python lambda function here for reference:

```
import base64
import gzip
import json
import logging

# Setup logging configuration
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def unpack_kinesis_stream_records(event):

    # decode and decompress each base64 encoded data element
    return [gzip.decompress(base64.b64decode(k["data"])).decode('utf-8') for k in event["records"]]

def decode_raw_cloud_trail_events(cloudTrailEventDataList):

    #Convert Raw Event Data List
    eventList =  [json.loads(e) for e in cloudTrailEventDataList]

    #Filter out-non DATA_MESSAGES
    filteredEvents = [e for e in eventList if e["messageType"] == 'DATA_MESSAGE']

    #Covert each indidual log Event Message
    events = []
    for f in filteredEvents:
        for e in f["logEvents"]:
            events.append(json.loads(e["message"]))

    logger.info("{0} Event Logs Decoded".format(len(events)))
    return events

def handle_request(event, context):

    #Log Raw Kinesis Stream Records
    #logger.debug(json.dumps(event, indent=4))

    # Unpack Kinesis Stream Records
    kinesisData = unpack_kinesis_stream_records(event)
    #[logger.debug(k) for k in kinesisData]

    # Decode and filter events
    events = decode_raw_cloud_trail_events(kinesisData)

    ####### INTEGRATION CODE GOES HERE #########

    return f"Successfully processed {len(events)} records."

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return handle_request(event, context)
```

Can anyone help me understand the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using 'kinesis firehose' service and not 'kinesis data stream'. code you are using is used to read directly from kinesis data stream and process cloudtrail events.

kinesis firehose data transformation lambda function is different. Firehose sends received cloudtrail events to lambda function. Lambda process/transform the events and should send those events back to firehose, so that firehose can deliver them to destination S3 bucket.

Your lambda function should return records in exactly same format as firehose expects them and each record should have either of the status [Dropped, Ok, or ProcessingFailed]. You can read more in aws [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html)